# Attempting to enter values to database tables using jdbc transaction

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm attempting to enter a set of values to tables reservation,resdetails using database transactions. There are no exceptions thrown, but values are not being entered in to DB.Here i've used utilised java.sql.PreparedStatement.

```
public boolean addReservation(Reservation res, ArrayList<ReservationDetails> resdetlist) throws Exception {
    connection = DBConnection.getDBConnection();
    try {
        System.out.println("A");
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement ps1 = connection.prepareStatement("insert into reservation values(?,?,?,?)");
        ps1.setString(1, res.getResid());
        ps1.setBoolean(2, res.isCheckin_status());
        ps1.setString(3, res.getRes_from());
        ps1.setString(4, res.getRes_till());
        int addedres = ps1.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("addres:" + addedres);
        System.out.println("B");
        if (addedres > 0) {
            for (ReservationDetails resdet : resdetlist) {
                //int addedresdet = addReservationDetails(resdet);
                PreparedStatement ps2 = connection.prepareStatement("insert into resdetails values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                ps2.setString(1, resdet.getResid());
                ps2.setString(2, resdet.getNic());
                ps2.setString(3, resdet.getPayment_id());
                ps2.setString(4, resdet.getRoom_no());
                ps2.setString(5, resdet.getType_of_accomodation());
                ps2.setString(6, resdet.getDate_of_reservation());
                int addedresdet = ps2.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("addedresdet:" + addedresdet);
                System.out.println("C");
                if (addedresdet <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("D");
                    connection.rollback();
                    return false;
                }
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("E");
            connection.rollback();
            return false;
        }
        connection.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // ex.printStackTrace();
        connection.rollback();
    } finally {
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        System.out.println("F");
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: I am guessing you need a commit line?

Answer (score 0):

If `executeUpdate()` returns `<= 0` then nothing changed in the database, therefore there's no need to rollback the transaction. Also, if a problem occurred while inserting the entry (eg. a constraint violation, etc) then the `executeUpdate()` throws a SQLException. I would change you code to:

```
try {
   connection.setAutoCommit(false);
   PreparedStatement ps1 = ...
   ...
   ps1.executeUpdate();
   for (ReservationDetails resdet : resdetlist) {
       PreparedStatement ps2 = ...
       ...
       ps2.executeUpdate();
   }
   connection.commit();
} catch (SQLException e) {
   connection.rollback();
}
```

Also, don't forget to call `close()` on the `PreparedStatements` after you use them, and on the `connection` object at the end of the method.

Comment: I made the changed exactly as stated above.Still no effect.

Comment: Are you seeing any exceptions? You're catching them in `catch (Exception ex)` but you're not printing them: `// ex.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Yeah there was an exception thrown.It was rectified.Anyway Thanks for pointing that out!!